# /bin/sh: 1: node: not found with child_process.exec

Tags: javascript, node.js

I tried to run a nodejs script with the built in `child_process` module and it works fine until i give it options. Specially when i add the `env` property to the options object.

```
let exec = require('child_process').exec;

exec('node random.js', { env: {} }, (err) => {
  console.log(err);
})
```

Then i get this error: `/bin/sh: 1: node: not found`.

I have node installed with nvm, maybe that is the cause, but don't know why.

Comment: Try with the full path to the node command.

Comment: dont want to hardwire to specific version

Comment: I say to do so to verify if the issue is you miss the path of your node installation directory. The new shell you're launching don't share the env with his parent process.

Comment: i fear that is the issue, but how to solve it?

Answer (score 4):

If you exec a new shell from your script this don't have the same environment of the parent shell (your script).

So you have to provide all the needed environment.

In your case I see 2 way you could do.

First: you create a node command with the full path:

```
let exec = require('child_process').exec;

let node_cmd = '/path/to/my/node/node';

exec(node_cmd + ' random.js', { env: {} }, (err) => {
  console.log(err);
});
```

So you could use env variables to handle the path, or just change it when you need.

Second, pass the path variable to the command:

```
let exec = require('child_process').exec;

let env_variables = 'PATH='+process.env.PATH;

let cmd = env_variables + ' node random.js';

exec(cmd, { env: {} }, (err) => {
  console.log(err);
});
```

Another way is using the [dotenv](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv) package.

Comment: [process.execPath](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/process.html#process_process_execpath) might be of help too.